# How I get a positive TimeSpan If the second DateTime is bigger then the first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, time, timespan

Hi I have a Problem with the TimeSpan in C#.

In my Application I calculate the difference of two time. How this ->

```
12:00:30 - 12:00:00 = 00:00:30
```

but my problem is if the second time is bigger then the first time...I get a negative number :(

```
1:00:00 - 23:00:00 = -22:00:00
```

But I want a positive number how this -->

```
1:00:00 - 23:00:00 -> 2:00:00
```

here my code:

```
private static int GetTimeSpan(string Out, string In) {

            try
            {
                TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Parse(In) - DateTime.Parse(Out);

                double TotalSec = diff.TotalSeconds;

                return (int)TotalSec;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can't you just check which one is bigger and substract other one from it?

Comment: How will you tell the difference between an exception and two may-or-may-not-be-times that are the same, e.g. `12:00:00-12:00:00` would be the same as `'fish'-'elephant'` for your code. Don't take strings as input, take a `DateTime/Timespan`.  A definite case of following the SRP.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`TimeSpan.Duration()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns the absolute value of a `TimeSpan`:

```
TimeSpan diff = (DateTime.Parse(In) - DateTime.Parse(Out)).Duration();
```

Comment: I get with you solution 22:00:00 hours but I want get 2:00:00 :(

Comment: @Tarasov: Well, that's because your in and out dates are different by 22 hours. What's the logic by which you want to get 2 hours as the result? What are the actual DateTime values?

Comment: @Jon, I suspect (and tried to show it in my answer) that OP wants second time to be always treated and predecessor of the first. So in the question's example 1:00 is treated as a time of next day. ANd difference between 1:00 today and 23:00 yesterday is indeed 2 hours

Comment: @Andrei: It looks like that, but I 'm not sure. I feel we need to know what's up with the date part because this kind of operation is highly unusual and frankly it feels wrong. What kind of real-world quantity would it model?

Comment: How I can create a new DateTime how (23:59:59)?

Comment: @Tarasov: A DateTime has a date *and* a time. You are only talking about times. Are you sure DateTime is the correct data type to use? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 DateTime dt1 =  DateTime.Parse(In);
 DateTime dt2 =  DateTime.Parse(Out);
 TimeSpan diff = (dt1>dt)? dt1- dt2 : dt2 - dt1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result of calculation, and if it is negative - add 24 hours to it to get complement time span:

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Parse(In) - DateTime.Parse(Out);
if (diff.TotalSeconds < 0) {
    diff = diff.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0,0));
}
```